# Como utilizar a função pow do C?

Tags: c

O programa não esta completo ainda, mas deveria pelo menos rodar a `função1`.
Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> /tmp/ccbRtCar.o: na função `funcao1':
> iniciosimulado02.c:(.text+0x18f): referência indefinida para `pow'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Segue o programa:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    imprimemenu();
    questao03(x);
    return (0);
}

int imprimemenu() {
    printf("\n(1)  funcao  1\n");
    printf("\n(2)  funcao  2\n");
    printf("\n(3)  funcao  3\n");
    printf("\n(0)  sair \n");
    return (0);
}

int questao03(int x) {
    int y;
    int z, a;
    while (x != 3) {
        printf("Escolha a opcao do menu: \n");
        scanf("%i", &x);
        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                printf("Digite o numeros do qual será extraída a raiz: \n");
                scanf("%i", &y);
                printf("Digite a ordem da raiz: \n");
                scanf("%i", &z);
                funcao1(y, z);
                printf("O resultado da conta deu: %i \n", a);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("essa funcao nao retorna \n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("essa funcao nao retorna \n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("valores entre 0 e 3\n");
        }
    }
}

int funcao1(int y, int z) {
    int k;
    k = pow(y, 1 / z);
    return (k);
}
```

Não consegui compreender muito bem o erro e,consequentemente não achei o local do erro.

Comment: Lucas, porque você está desfazendo as edições? Elas tem o intuito de deixar a questão mais legivel.

Comment: Sem querer,desculpa!

Comment: Você consegue me ajudar no meu erro?

Comment: Como você está compilando?

Comment: gcc nome_do_arquivo.c -o nome_do_arquivo.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa passar o parâmetro `-lm` para o gcc para habilitar a ligação com a biblioteca matemática.

Fica assim:

```
gcc nome_do_arquivo.c -o nome_do_arquivo.exe -lm
```

Comment: obridago,esqueci que tinha colocado a biblioteca math.vlw